# Implementing Proxy pattern via concrete inheritance

Tags: design-patterns, proxy

Say I have some code which consumes a class called `Subject`, which implements `ISubject`.
Would there be any concerns if I were to build a `ProxySubject`, which inherits `Subject`?

I like this style because it makes it so simple to wrap the real subject: `ProxySubject` inherits `Subject` and overrides the required fields (mostly relying upon `ThisBase.ThatOverridenProperty`). If the targeted fields are not virtual (not overridable), then you can always re-implement `ISubject` directly from `ProxySubject`.

I did not find any suggestions for doing so; which makes me wonder it might actually not be such a good idea?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use the proxy pattern here? It sounds like you want ordinary inheritance, without any particular design patterns?

Comment: Understand [the yo-yo problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem) before doing this.

Comment: @Amon, for example to cache some fields: the field returns a [value holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Value_holder), which itself references the field in the base class. This way the base class implements the behaviour without any concerns for costly operations, and then the proxy wrapps the required fields.

Comment: @candied_orange Actually, this is precisely what I wish to avoid: by inheriting and overriding, you do not need for example to re-assign the interface implementation. The behaviour and the interface assignment are handled by `RealSubject`, whilst `ProxySubject` only overrides where required, solely for the purpose of proxy-ing.

Comment: One obvious disadvantage is that you cannot rely on lazy instantiation, since instantiating the proxy subject will inevitably instantiate the real subject.